# Angular 2 Final Release IE11 TypeError: Object doesn't support this action

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 2 application and was originally experiencing issues in Internet Explorer versions 10 and 11 as described in my post here: [Angular 2 Release (2.0.1) Internet Explorer (SystemJS) Syntax Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41578928/angular-2-release-2-0-1-internet-explorer-systemjs-syntax-error/41964882#41964882).

For some reason, that error is gone (maybe from the answer posted on that question), but now I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Object doesn't support this action
   at MyAppService.prototype.myFunction(eval code:64:9)
   at Anonymous function (eval code:359:21)
   at SafeSubscriber.prototype.__tryOrUnsub (eval code:223:13)
   at SafeSubscriber.prototype.next (eval code:172:17)
   at Subscriber.prototype._next (eval code:125:9)
   at Subscriber.prototype.next (eval code:89:13)
   at MapSubscriber.prototype._next (eval code:83:9)
   at Subscriber.prototype.next (eval code:89:13)
   at onLoad (eval code:1230:25)
   at ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask (http://localhost:56159/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:234:17)
```

where `MyAppService` is a service I have created and `myFunction` is a function defined within that service, that I am calling from my component.

Although I would like the issue is related possibly to the shims - I have both es-5 and es-6 loaded:

```
<script src="./node_modules/es5-shim/es5-shim.js"></script>
<script src="./node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js"></script>
```

downloaded via npm just earlier today, above all my other angular scripts.

The application works fine in both Chrome and Firefox

Any ideas?

Comment: Hey @blubberbo, how have you solved this issue?

Comment: @DanielKucal you know, my focus was moved from that project to a different one and I haven't looked at it in a while. I guess the answer is I'm not really sure. Sorry I can't be of more help!

Comment: I see, thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

if anyone is facing similar issue, you need to include url-polyfill cos IE doesn't support URL. npm i url-polyfill and importing that in polfills.ts file. This was the issue in my case.